# How to create a directory in /var folder with parent directories using CodeIgniter 4 in a Docker container with Ubuntu image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am working on a CodeIgniter 4 project inside a Docker container with an Ubuntu image. As part of my application functionality, I need to create a new directory inside the /var folder. To achieve this, I have used the **mkdir($path, 0755, true)** function to create the directory and its parent directories if they don't exist.

However, when making API calls from within the Docker container, I encounter the following error: "mkdir(): Permission denied".

Upon further investigation, I realized that the web server within the Docker container does not have the necessary permissions to create directories in the /var folder.

I have verified the file permissions inside the container, and everything seems to be correctly set. However, the issue persists.

Could there be any specific Docker configurations or permissions that I need to adjust to allow my CodeIgniter 4 application to create directories inside the /var folder?

I am seeking guidance and solutions to resolve this permission issue in the context of running a CodeIgniter 4 application within a Docker container with an Ubuntu image.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem would be highly appreciated.

```html
 public function get_server_path($service)
    {
        $path = '/var/content'.'/'.$service.'/';
        if ( !is_dir( $path ) )
            shell_exec( "mkdir -p {$path}" );
        return $path;
    }
```

Dockerfile :

```html
# Use the official Ubuntu 20.04 base image
FROM ubuntu:jammy

ENV TZ=UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Stop dpkg-reconfigure tzdata from prompting for input
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install apache and php7
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
        apache2 \
        libapache2-mod-php \
        libapache2-mod-auth-openidc \
        php-bcmath \
        php-cli \
        php-curl \
        php-mbstring \
        php-gd \
        php-mysql \
        php-json \
        php-ldap \
        php-memcached \
        php-mime-type \
        php-pgsql \
        php-tidy \
        php-intl \
        php-xmlrpc \
        php-soap \
        php-uploadprogress \
        php-zip \
        php-redis \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


# Enable Apache mods
RUN a2enmod php8.1

# Set Apache configurations
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/html/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


# Copy your PHP application to the container
COPY . /var/www/html


# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache in the foreground
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Comment: Post your docker file.

Comment: @bassxzero  I have updated the question. Please review that.

Comment: Why don't you try adding `RUN chmod -R 0777 /var/content`  to your docker file? It's not a good fix, but it will at least tell you if it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Appreciate your answer but this was not right way.

Comment: I'm well aware this isn't the correct way. The correct way is to change the user that apache runs as and then change the owner of `/var/content` to the new user, BUT i wanted to make sure permissions were the problem before doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am waiting for the other dev's answer.